# MATLAB: Why my Pixel Indices are so different from that in Spatial Coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, projection

The question is revised to make it more specific and constructive.

I am doing imtransform, yet the xdata and ydata are very much different from that of size(output).

[ output, xdata, ydata ] = imtransform( imgDouble{1}, tform );

Real data test:

```
K>> size(output)

ans =

         854        1230

K>> xdata(2) - xdata(1)

ans =

   1.6635e+03

K>> ydata(2) - ydata(1)

ans =

  876.1373
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imtransform.html), imtransform sometimes rescales the data if the output image would be 'excessively large'. You can force it to match the scale of the input image by adding the input argument 'XYScale' and setting it to 1.

If the output is still not what you expect (and you've double-checked the transform), you may also need to set the output size of the image by either giving an input argument for 'size' or for 'xdata' and 'ydata'.

It's not quite entirely clear what you're trying to do with the rest of the code, but if you have a set of coordinates which defines the location of some point or points of interest (inlier_array?), and you want to know where they'd end up after the transform, that's exactly what tformfwd does.

If your transform includes a translation I suggest reading through [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/performing-general-2-d-spatial-transformations.html), particularly "Understanding the Coordinates of the Transformed Image".

Comment: Thanks for related information. But since the destination coordinates are wrong, we still need some extra helps. And extra information about the question is added.

Answer (score 0):

It is about [Expressing Image Locations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html#brcu_cr).

There are two kinds of image location expression,

One and the most common one is the

pixel indices:

in row and column

The other one is Intrinsic Coordinate System:

express in x and y:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/intro_r_1.png